# Replace mem::uninitialized with MaybeUninit

Tags: rust, initialization, maybeuninit

I'm working on a project around embedded systems that needs to use filesystem. I want to use liitlefs crate in rust but it uses **mem::uninitialized** that deprecated since 1.39.0 .
https://github.com/brandonedens/rust-littlefs

```
pub struct LittleFs<T: Storage> {
    storage: T,
    lfs_config: lfs::lfs_config,
    lfs: lfs::lfs_t,
    read_buffer: [u8; READ_SIZE],
    prog_buffer: [u8; PROG_SIZE],
    lookahead_buffer: [u8; LOOKAHEAD / 8],
}

impl<T: Storage> LittleFs<T> {
    /// Create a new instance of the LittleFS.
    pub fn new(storage: T) -> Self {
        LittleFs {
            storage: storage,
            lfs: unsafe { mem::uninitialized::<lfs::lfs>() },
            lfs_config: unsafe { mem::uninitialized::<lfs::lfs_config>() },
            read_buffer: [0u8; READ_SIZE],
            prog_buffer: [0u8; PROG_SIZE],
            lookahead_buffer: [0u8; LOOKAHEAD / 8],
        }
    }
```

I tried to replace it in the following way but it caused unspecified behaviors by the system:

```
pub struct LittleFs<T: Storage> {
    storage: T,
    lfs_config: lfs::lfs_config,
    lfs: lfs::lfs_t,
    read_buffer: [u8; READ_SIZE],
    prog_buffer: [u8; PROG_SIZE],
    lookahead_buffer: [u8; LOOKAHEAD / 8],
}

impl<T: Storage> LittleFs<T> {
    pub fn new(storage: T) -> Self {
        LittleFs {
            storage,
            lfs: unsafe { MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init() },
            lfs_config: unsafe { MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init() },
            read_buffer: [0u8; READ_SIZE],
            prog_buffer: [0u8; PROG_SIZE],
            lookahead_buffer: [0u8; LOOKAHEAD / 8],
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't do `uninit().assume_init()` -- it's definitely *not* initialized. `assume_init()` is only to be called once the data *is* initialized with real values. You'll need to change `lfs` to `MaybeUninit<lfs::lfs_t>` and then deal with the downstream modifications needed in any code that accesses the field.

Comment: You'll need `MaybeUninit` fields, or to return `MaybeUninit<Self>`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use that crate? It hasn't been updated in 3 years - not something what I would rely on.

Comment: @JohnKugelman If I do this then how can I rewrite this function for example:             
`pub fn format(&mut self) -> Result<(), FsError> {         self.lfs_config.write(self.create_lfs_config());                                                                  let res = unsafe { lfs::lfs_format(&mut self.lfs, &self.lfs_config) };                   lfs_to_fserror(res)}`

Comment: `MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init()` is basically the same as `mem::uninitialized()`, and the reason it was deprecated is because it is UB for most types.

Comment: This crate is crap. Calling any method on `LittleFs` without first calling `mount` or `format` means it uses the uninitialized lfs handle - something against the "no memory unsafety without `unsafe`" contract that safe rust is supposed to uphold. Similar issues with the `File` and `Dir` types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do `uninit().assume_init()` — it's definitely *not* initialized. `assume_init()` is only to be called once the data has been initialized with real values. The idea behind calling it is that you're promising, "Yes, I know this value is marked as *maybe* initialized. I promise that it *is* initialized now. It's not just a *maybe*."

You'll need to change the types of `lfs` and `lfs_config`:

```
lfs_config: MaybeUninit<lfs::lfs_config>,
lfs: MaybeUninit<lfs::lfs_t>,
```

That will have a ripple effect downstream, requiring you to then modify any code that accesses the fields.

- Initialize them with [`write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#method.write).
- Read them with [`assume_init_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#method.assume_init_ref) or [`assume_init_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#method.assume_init_mut).